# ActivityNotFound Exception when using dynamic feature on some devices

Tags: android, kotlin, android-multidex, dynamic-feature-module, activitynotfoundexception

I maintain an Android product where I've modularized several components into dynamic features. During the final packaging stage, I use packageReleaseUniversalApk to bundle all modules into a single APK, which is then published on Google Play. However, when I monitor error logs from users, I occasionally encounter reports of ActivityNotFoundException when users attempt to launch activities from dynamic features. I haven't been able to replicate this issue on my machine or those of my colleagues. I believe it's not a widespread problem. How should I go about resolving this issue?

the AndroidManifest setting of app

`<dist:module dist:instant="false" />`

the Dynamic Feature Module AndroidManifest Setting.

`

```
<dist:module
    dist:instant="false"
    dist:title="@string/xxxx">
    <dist:delivery>
        <dist:install-time />
    </dist:delivery>
    <dist:fusing dist:include="true" />
</dist:module>

<application>
    <activity android:name=".XXXXActivity"/>
</application>
```

`

I have no idea what went wrong , can anyone please help to give an suggestion on how to solving the issue?

I have no idea, cause this issue only occur on quite a few devices of my customer, I never reproduce the issue on my end. I wonder whether it is a multidex issue. But since my app targetSDK is 24 or higher, so I do not think I need to add multidex library in gradle.

the exception detail info is as below.
Unable to find explicit activity class {us.video.test/us.video.test.submodule.XXXXActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

the way I start the dynamic module activity is as below.

```
val splitInstallManager =
                SplitInstallManagerFactory.create(GlobalVariable.applicationCtx)
            if (splitInstallManager.installedModules.contains(moduleName)) {
                val i = Intent()
                i.setClassName(
                    us.video.test.BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID,
                    "$modulePackageName.$activityName"
                )
                i.setPackage(modulePackageName)
                i.putExtra(Constants.ARG_PROJECT_INFO, projectInfo?.toByteArray())
                launcher?.let {
                    it.launch(i)
                } ?: let {
                    context.startActivity(i)
                }
            }
```